# Getting value from object dictionary C#

Tags: c#, json, object, dictionary, converters

I am using the LiveConnect sdk to get some user info.
After doing whatever is necessary for that, this is the result I'm getting:

```
{
   "id": "123456789", 
   "name": "a b", 
   "first_name": "a", 
   "last_name": "b", 
   "link": "https://profile.live.com/", 
   "work": [], 
   "gender": null, 
   "emails": {
      "preferred": "a@live.com", 
      "account": "a@live.com", 
      "personal": null, 
      "business": null
   }, 
   "addresses": {
      "personal": {
         "street": null, 
         "street_2": null, 
         "city": null, 
         "state": null, 
         "postal_code": null, 
         "region": null
      }, 
      "business": {
         "street": null, 
         "street_2": null, 
         "city": null, 
         "state": null, 
         "postal_code": null, 
         "region": null
      }
   }, 
   "locale": "en_US", 
   "updated_time": "2013-10-10T08:41:14+0000"
}
```

I need to get the `"account"` inside `"emails"`.
First, when I got this string I did the following:

```
public Dictionary<string, object> userData = new Dictionary<string, object>();

userData = deserializeJsonObject(<the string above>);

private Dictionary<string, object> deserializeJsonObject(string json)
{
    var jss = new JavaScriptSerializer();
    var d = jss.Deserialize<Dictionary<string, object>>(json);
    return d;
}
```

Now, in order to get the account email, I was going to do something like:

```
string email = userData["emails"]["account"];
```

but since this is a string, object dictionary, I get an error that it's not possible because userData["emails"] is an object.

How can I get the data?

Comment: You could make it a `Dictionary<string, dynamic>`, and then it would work doing: `userData["emails"]["preferred"];`

Comment: awesome! thanks! it is better than casting?

Comment: I'd only say it's better in that you don't need to bother casting anything...but you lose some readability. After all, casting it shows instantly what the object will be, using `dynamic` you won't know until you compile & run your program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do you had tried to make a cast?

for example:

`(userData["emails"] as Dictionary<string,object>)["account"]`

or:

`((Dictionary<string,object>)userData["emails"])["account"]`

Comment: which one is better btw?

Comment: i think the first one, because you don't need to cast the object, just specificy the type